# UML class diagram metamodel

Tags: class, uml, metamodel, mda, eclipse-atl

Where can I find a simplified class diagram metamodel ?
It's for a ATL ATLAS Transformation Language project, I need to transform a entity class diagram to SQL database.
thank you .

Comment: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/classifier.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (I´m now leading the atlanmod team, creator of the ATL language) have a "[zoo of metamodels](http://www.emn.fr/z-info/atlanmod/index.php/Zoos)" with more than 200 metamodels in different formats, including ecore ones ready to use with ATL.

In fact we also have an [ATL Transformation zoo](http://www.eclipse.org/atl/atlTransformations/) with more than 100 ATL transformations you can experiment with (and learn from)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [simplified class diagram metamodel](http://app.genmymodel.com/class-diagram/examples/simple-class-metamodel), based on EMOF.

Answer (score 0):

You could test MOSKitt (www.moskitt.org), modeling software kitt based on eclipse where you could find different modules including a transformation from UML Class diagram to Database using ATL and SQL code generation to different technologies (postgre, mysql, etc)